# Timer Class - Give an error if the start timer is invoke twice in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

how do I invoke an error if the start timer class function is invoke twice ? Thanks

```
import time
class Timer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._startTime = None
        self._endTime = None

    def start(self):
        self._startTime = time.time() if self._startTime is None else print('Started')

    def end(self):
        self._endTime = time.time()
        print('seconds',self._endTime - self._startTime)
t = Timer()
t.start()
t.start() # should give an error
```

Comment: `raise` an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a instance variable (if you want 1 invocation per class instance) or class variable (only 1 invocation in entire lifecycle as class variable is shared by all instances of class) to keep count of number of invocations and when count exceeds some threshold (In your case it's 1), you can raise an exception. Something like this:

```
import time
class Timer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._startTime = None
        self._endTime = None
        self.count = 0 # Instance variable, which allows 1 invocation per instance of this class

    def start(self):
        self.count+=1
        if self.count == 2: # Threshold is 2 here
            raise Exception # You custom exception here
        self._startTime = time.time() if self._startTime is None else print('Started')

    def end(self):
        self._endTime = time.time()
        print('seconds',self._endTime - self._startTime)
```

Refer [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3) for more details about class variables vs instance variable in Python.